# How to ignore Get-AzStorageBlobContent NullReferenceException error as file still downloads

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, blobstorage

I have a PSScript works, but the command Get-AzStorageBlobContent always throws the same error when file still downloads, even the script is compete and I verified the files are downloaded to the specified local folder sucessfully, how to ignore these errors?
I tried to catch the error and just ignored it, but looks like it won't come to catch section.
[image]
For each blob image, it has one error throwing, as you can see it doesn't step into the catch statement (the screeshot 1). How to ignore below error? or just get warning?
[image]

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue as well. But for what's it worth, we can try this way to download the blob: [Get a blob object and save it in a variable, then download blob content with the blob object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-9.7.1#example-4-get-a-blob-object-and-save-it-in-a-variable-then-download-blob-content-with-the-blob-object). This command does not throw any exceptions given that you have set the `Context` properly for the storage account.

Comment: Got it, make it to two steps, thanks Jay

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command (**`ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`**) to avoid errors and continue the execution of the command in the console.

**Command:**

```
$repo= "your-local-path"
$blobUri="<your-blob-uri>"

Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Uri $blobUri -Destination $repo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

**Output:**

```
   AccountName: <Your-account-name>, ContainerName: <container-name>

Name                 BlobType  Length          ContentType                    LastModified         AccessTier SnapshotTime              
----                 --------  ------          -----------                    ------------         ---------- ------------              
sample.mp4           BlockBlob 1055736         application/octet-stream       2023-05-09 05:41:28Z Hot
```

[image]

Otherwise, try assigning  **`Get-AzStorageBlobContent`** command as a variable like the below:

```
$repo= "your-local-path"
$blobUri="<your-blob-uri>"
try{
$blobcontent=Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Uri $blobUri -Destination $repo
Write-Host $blobcontent.name
Write-Host $blobcontent.length
}
catch{
Write-Host "nullreference exception"
}
```

**Output:**

```
sample.mp4
1055736
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Everything you wanted to know about exceptions - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.3#tryfinally)

Comment: Thanks so much Venkatesan, these are exactly what I was looking for! Both ways work well and nice reference too!